# Запуск Activity из onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

После добавления объекта необходимо дважды вызвать одну Activity (SizeDialog) для ввода разных параметров. Проблема в том, что после первого вызова данные приходят, а после второго нет. Вот упрощённый код, очищенный от всего лишнего:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_OBJECT:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String selected_object = data.getStringExtra(GoodsListActivity.SELGOOD);
                addObject(selected_object);

                Intent intentSize = new Intent(this, SizeDialog.class);
                intentSize.putExtra("dialog_title", getResources().getString(R.string.object_width));
                startActivityForResult(intentSize, ACTIVITY_WIDTH);
            }
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_WIDTH:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                int selectedObjectID = objects_list.getCheckedItemPosition();

                if (selectedObjectID == -1) {
                    return;
                }

                float width_value = data.getFloatExtra(SizeDialog.SIZEVALUE);
                SetObjectWidth(selectedObjectID, width_value);

                Intent intentSize = new Intent(this, SizeDialog.class);
                intentSize.putExtra("dialog_title", getResources().getString(R.string.object_height));
                startActivityForResult(intentSize, ACTIVITY_HEIGHT);
            }
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_HEIGHT:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                int selectedObjectID = objects_list.getCheckedItemPosition();

                if (selectedObjectID == -1) {
                    return;
                }

                float height_value = data.getFloatExtra(SizeDialog.SIZEVALUE);
                SetObjectHeight(selectedObjectID, height_value);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12691638/3212712) (первая строка выдачи гугла на запрос

> [onactivityresult not called second](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=onactivityresult%20not%20called%20second)

)

проблема в том, что активити, коя должна возвращать результат не завершается до повторного её вызова. Засим можно решить проблему принудительно её остановив переопределив её метод `onStop()`:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    finish();
    super.onStop();
}
```